# opencv2 - python - Inpaint Not working with Jpg

Tags: python, opencv

This is my first experience using the opencv lib. I have a problem. The opencv2 inpaint is working on my first example using .tiff image format.
[image]

Then i tried to try next example. But the result is dissapointing.
[image]

Do you guys have any explanation of this? did i write a wrong implementation?

This is my code :

```js
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def main():
    imgpath = "sample.jpg"
    maskpath = "sample-mask.jpg"
    img = cv2.imread(imgpath, 1)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    mask = cv2.imread(maskpath, 0)

    output1 = cv2.inpaint(img, mask, 5, cv2.INPAINT_TELEA)

    output2 = cv2.inpaint(img, mask, 5, cv2.INPAINT_NS)

    output = [img, mask, output1, output2]
    titles = ['Damaged Image', 'Mask', 'TELEA', 'NS']

    for i in range(4):
        plt.subplot(2, 2, i + 1)
        if i == 1:
            plt.imshow(output[i], cmap='gray')
        else:
            plt.imshow(output[i])
        plt.title(titles[i])
        plt.xticks([])
        plt.yticks([])
    plt.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: ... and also please add your **actual** images rather than screen-grabs of them which potentially are of a totally different type and quality.

Comment: i added code. the actual image is just the same but different resolution.

Comment: the jpeg mask is probably NOT binary... it will have many non zero pixels due to compression artifacts.

Comment: Please post all your source and result images separately and not a screen snap showing them all together. Save them to disk individually not as grid of images. My guess is that you saved your map as JPG, which is a lossy compression and will change color values so that you do not have a binary image.